# Is there a Firefox addon to remove <video> elements with right-click menu item?

Tags: firefox-addon, html5-video, firefox-developer-edition

The inspector in Developer Edition allows you to remove any element you choose with one click; I wish there was a simple way to automatically NOT play or download HTML5 `<video>` elements unless I click on them - I am forced to download large files I do not want when browsing web. Any way to turn off video elements that will automatically download without disabling them completely?

Is there a way to get some JavaScript run for every page load that could enforce this behaviour, other than putting ' video: { display: none; } ' in user CSS stylesheet? Is there a 'user library.js' that Firefox will run for every page load I'd like to be able to ONLY download & play videos I  click on. I can write the JavaScript to do this easy, but how to get it loaded by Firefox for every page?

Comment: That's a basic feature included in firefox (and a lot of other browsers). Ask on SuperUser or, most likely, find a post where someone asked already.

Comment: If I could find that, I wouldn't have posted this. 
Even though normal flash / mpeg4 / youtube player elements 
do not autoplay, I have noticed that some HTML5 <video> elements do.
Using FFMPEG / gstreamer. I just wondered if there was any plugin for this.

Answer (score -2):

Aha! I found the answer:

`about:config` -> `media.autoplay.enabled`

This is described at: https://www.howtogeek.com/227669/how-to-stop-auto-playing-html5-videos-in-your-web-browser/